# Is good idea foreach over foreach transform to one simple reduce? how can it?

Tags: javascript, foreach, reduce

I have this piece of code

```
  res['result'].forEach(result => {
    result.requestDocumentEntities.forEach(entitie => {
      newResult.push(entitie);
    });
  });
```

- I am trying to optimize it in 1 single line.
- It would be good idea to use reduce?
- How can I apply it?

Comment: this doesn't seem like it needs optimization...

Comment: You can `.concat()` the value of `result.requestDocumentEntities` onto `newResult`, which won't really be "optimized" much but it'll save the inner `.forEach`

Comment: If your looking for a one line solution, you could remove the braces... `res['result'].forEach(result => result.requestDocumentEntities.forEach(entitie => newResult.push(entitie)));`. Just remember that adding more filtering functions just means more loops your code has to run.

Comment: I thought the solution could go through using `reduce`or `filter`. But it seems that no

Comment: Note that the functional approach is slower in JS, loops are more optimized in term of performance (and usually more easily understandable at first look). A thing that lots of people seem to forget these days here..